# DLookUp #Error and flickering using SQL to query a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic, combobox

I am using Access to track help desk calls. I have a form that has four categorization options *Topic* box, *Department* box, *SubTopic* box, and *ResolutionUpdate* box.  Currently, regardless of *Topi*c, the *ResolutionUpdate* box will show all options available.

What I want to do is have the form show only those options that are available for the chosen topic in the *Topic* box.  For example, if in the *Topic* box I choose a country name I would only want the *ResolutionUpdate* box to show the city's inside that country. I've been able to accomplish this goal, unfortunately, it causes my help desk suggested article text box to quit working. Specifically, it will display `#ERROR` and blink repeatedly.

The following is the Row Source from Access for my *ReslutionUpdate* box.

```
SELECT [qryResolution].[Resolution] FROM qryResolution ORDER BY [Resolution];
```

The above SQL code was generated by the Combo Box Wizard in Access. I have yet to implement the necessary steps so my ResolutionUpdate box so it will be dynamic. It's at this point that I noticed my suggested help desk article text box will show `#Error` and begin blinking.

This is what I currently have in my text box.

```
=DLookUp("[ICDocID]","Reference","[Resolution]= " & [ResolutionUpdate])
```

What should I do to stop the text box from blinking and generating `#Error`?

Comment: Please edit your post. I tried formatting for readability but there are a number of issues including invalid SQL as `ORDER BY` needs a field name and misspellings. Please post actual code. If *Resolution* is a string field, how does first expression work? Is *cboResolution* also string? If so, quotes need to be used in criteria argument

Comment: Please let me know if that is better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As mentioned, strings need to be wrapped in quotes in the criteria argument of `DLookup`. Try; `DLookUp("[ICDocID]","Reference","[Resolution]= '" & [ResolutionUpdate] & "'")`. Also, what you need is more likely [conditional comboboxes](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html). Not sure how DLookUp works here.

Comment: Make sure that the controls, fields, and global variables all have different names. Use Hungarian notation if it helps. You seem to have a circular reference or circular update loop: it's not clear which.